# How to join a swarm, initialized on Docker host, from a virtual machine

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

It maybe a trivial question but I failed to find appropriate answer to it. I have a Docker for Windows installed on my Widnows 10 machine. It uses Hyper-V to create initial virtual machine for Docker (MobyLinuxVM). I can operate Docker from CMD as was expected. I believe it is Docker host I'm managing. Then I initialize swarm mode for the host running the next command

```
docker swarm init
```

It shows me my only node in the swarm.

```
C:\Users\Andrei\Gospace\src\docker-swarm\Proj>docker node ls
ID                            HOSTNAME                STATUS              AVAILABILITY        MANAGER STATUS      ENGINE VERSION
vzt4bw76ucl139f3u94ms6i6e *   linuxkit-00155df56803   Ready               Active              Leader              18.06.1-ce
```

My intention is to create a new virtual machine and join it as another node to the swarm. For this I follow this tutorial for Windows

[https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/get-started/part4/][1]

creating a virtual switch of external type and using it when creating a new machine with the following command

```
docker-machine create --driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "Hotspot Switch" hotspot0
```

With `docker swarm join-token worker` command I get the command to join the swarm

```
To add a worker to this swarm, run the following command:

    docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-53lc6spjk0no0dn3kc4s3zlgx5xuszdvdddw1uy1mirlerkimf-1jjymklcjt5lo660pm7hd8t29 192.168.65.3:2377
```

Then I ssh into the machine I created and try it but get the next error:

```
docker@hotspot0:~$ docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-53lc6spjk0no0dn3kc4s3zlgx5xuszdvdddw1uy1mirlerkimf-1jjymklcjt5lo660pm7hd8t29 192.168.6
5.3:2377
Error response from daemon: Timeout was reached before node joined. The attempt to join the swarm will continue in the background. Use the "docker info" command to see the current swarm status of your node.
```

I've been searching the Internet for the fair amount of time but couldn't find simple and clear answer to how it could be done or why it shouldn't be done at all. I have a notion that there is something wrong with chosen attempt to use Docker but it is the only way I see to create an image from Dockerfile without pushing and pulling it to/from Docker hub and share it with a service in the swarm. I would appreciate if you could steer me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

BTW, everything works fine if I create two machines and create a swarm with them. The issue is when I try to bind the host (which is actually not a docker machine by design) and a machine created with `docker-machine create`.